# Find all unmet dependencies for a Python/Django project

Tags: python, code-analysis, pypi

I've been handed a dozen or so legacy Django applications to maintain. The first part of this process is moving them off their ancient Ubuntu 9.04 server (which is *long* out of support) onto something fresh and safe.

But the projects don't include any sort of dependency listing. From habit I'm used to generating a `requirements.txt` file as I develop a site and that makes redeployment a simple and automated process.

As it stands I would have to manually step through these projects, making sure to scrape every corner to find possible missing dependencies. Either that or I install *everything*.

Is there an automated code-analysis option here? Something that can use to scan the local project directories for each project to generate a list of packages it needs... ideally in PyPI formatted package names.

Comment: You could script something up to search for `import x` and `from x import y` statements, and then run all those statements in the target environment to see which work and which dont...

Answer (score 1):

[`z3c.dependencychecker`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.dependencychecker) can be used for this purpose.

It's in the `z3c` namespace, but from what I know that's only because it has been developed with a Zope ecosystem in mind, but it can just as well be used for plain Python projects. Unless you want to run its tests, it does not have any dependencies on Zope packages.

It does however only consider dependencies declared in `setup.py`, not in `requirements.txt`. But it should be pretty easy to sync up missing dependencies for the full list of dependencies once they've been determined.

Usage:

- Activate your virtualenv, and install `z3c.dependencychecker`, e.g. by doing `pip install z3c.dependencychecker`
- Make sure you have run `python setup.py develop` for your project recently, so you have an up-to-date `*.egg-info`.
- `cd` into your projects source directory
- run `dependencychecker`

Note that `z3c.dependencychecker` isn't perfect (pretty much by definition, because of the way it works), so it can report some false positives. But in my experience it's a very good start, and it should be pretty easy to verify why it reported a particular dependency, and weed out false positives.